# Knp Paginator with search form

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, knppaginator

I'm trying to use KNP paginator with a form-search.

Everything works fine, but when I go to page 2 they send me back to page 2 without the result of the search.

I used POST methods on my twig because if I use GET methods, nothing happening.

I found many post on my issue but I don't know how can I resolve it. If someone has some advices for me, please can you help me please.

This is my code :

```html
public function rechercheAction() {
        $form = $this->createForm(RechercheClientType::class);
        return $this->render('admin/client/recherche.html.twig',[
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ]
        );
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/admin/client/recherche", name="recherche_client")
     */
    public function rechercheTraitementAction(PaginatorInterface $paginator,Request $request) {


        $session = $request->getSession();


        $form = $this->createForm(RechercheClientType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $query = $this->repository->recherche($form['rechercheClient']->getData());

        $users = $paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $request->query->getInt('page',1), 10
        );

        //Compte le nombre d'éléments recherchés
        $count = count($query);




        return $this->render('admin/client/data-tables.html.twig',[
                'users' => $users,
                'count' =>$count,
            ]
        );
    }
```

```html
<!-- recherche.html.twig -->
<form action="{{ path('recherche_client') }}" method="post">
{{ form_widget(form.rechercheClient, { 'attr': { 'class' : "form-control",'placeholder': "Rechercher par ID, nom , prénom, mail ou société"} }) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
</form>

<!-- data-table.html.twig -->
  <div class="" style="float:right">

   {{ knp_pagination_render(users) }}


   </div>
```

```html
public function recherche($chaine) {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->andWhere('u.nom like :chaine')
        ->orWhere('u.prenom like :chaine')
        ->orWhere('u.email like :chaine')
        ->orWhere('u.societe like :chaine')
        ->orderBy('u.id')
        ->setParameter('chaine','%'.$chaine.'%')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Please provide us with your repository code.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll give you

Answer (score 2):

Amigo I had the same issue but since we have interpreted the code differently I am gonna show my example.

```
$searchForm = $this->createFormBuilder($property)
            ->add('type', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Type::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'mapped' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
                'label' => false,
            ])
            ->add('filter', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-outline-dark btn-rounded waves-effect'
                ]
            ])
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->getForm();
```

the `->setMethod('GET')` made the difference

Comment: Thanks, Mike, that works indeed. How did you solve the issue that the token is sent via url as well ? I have that URI here which has search%5B_token%5D sent here.

```/?search%5Btitle%5D=list&search%5Burl%5D=onet.pl&search%5B_token%5D=gnBt1VgQSypvD4aRpG0kEyF0x2dV6X7zfb_WrYw4Ksw
```